# jQuery fadeIn and slideUp with delay

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

Hoping someone can help... I currently have a set of posts/divs inside Wordpress that I have set to fade in one by one using jQuery.

Essentially like these posts here: https://undsgn.com/uncode/blog/blog-boxed-grid?id=index-15588655905&ucat=7 When you click a filter they all fade in and slide up one by one.

I'd like to add to this a slideUp effect, so the slide up and fade in at the same time. I'm struggling to add the second effect and I'm getting unpredictable results.

The code I have so far is as follows:

HTML

```
<div class="fade-in-post-container">
  <div class="elementor-post">test</div>
  <div class="elementor-post">test</div>
  <div class="elementor-post">test</div>
  <div class="elementor-post">test</div>
  <div class="elementor-post">test</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.elementor-post {float:left; margin-right:20px;}
.fade-in-post-container .elementor-post { display: none; }
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(".fade-in-post-container .elementor-post").each(function(i) {
    jQuery(this).delay(500 * i).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/shan_2000_uk/kugc7m61/16/

I've tried this:

```
jQuery(".fade-in-post-container .elementor-post").each(function(i) {
    jQuery(this).delay(250 * i).fadeIn(1000).slideUp(1000);
});
```

and a couple of other things, but I can't seem to get it working properly...

Thanks a lot for taking the time to look.

Comment: You can use the framework ScrollReveal https://scrollrevealjs.org/ if you want to simplify things

Comment: Thanks, Krishanu - But I don't think that would simplify things - I feel I'm almost there and just missing a vital part...

Comment: Then you can try adding classes through jQuery instead of changing properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly do this just with CSS and without jQuery. If the effect below is what you are after. Hope it helps.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
}

.fade-in-post-container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 300px;
}


.elementor-post {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  animation: fadeIn 1s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.elementor-post:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.elementor-post:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.elementor-post:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.elementor-post:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.elementor-post:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 100px;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fade-in-post-container">
  <div class="elementor-post">test</div>
  <div class="elementor-post">test</div>
  <div class="elementor-post">test</div>
  <div class="elementor-post">test</div>
  <div class="elementor-post">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Gerard, thanks for this, it looks great but as this will be used for blog posts, I wouldn't know how many nth-child's there would be - it could be infinite. This with a bit of code that says increase the animation delay by 1 second for each nth-child would work, but I wouldnt know where to start with that or even if its possible

Answer (score 1):

i don't know is that exactly whats your looking for but check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anaselalami/kugc7m61/18/) example.

```
jQuery(".fade-in-post-container .elementor-post").each(function(i) {
    jQuery(this).delay(250 * i).fadeIn(1000,function() {
            $(this).delay(250 * i).slideUp(1000)
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can animate without queue (at the same time):

```
jQuery(this).animate({ opacity: 0 }, { duration: 1000, queue: false });
jQuery(this).animate({ height: 0 }, { duration: 1000, queue: false });
```

Working code:

```js
$('#run').click(function() {
  $('.fade-in-post-container .elementor-post').animate({ opacity: 1 }, { duration: 4000, queue: false });
  $('.fade-in-post-container .elementor-post').animate({ marginTop: 0 }, { duration: 2000, queue: false });
});
```

```css
.fade-in-post-container {

}

.fade-in-post-container .elementor-post {
  width: 25%;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin: 1%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 300px;
  opacity: 0;
}

#run {

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="run">Run effect</button>

<div class="fade-in-post-container">
  <div class="elementor-post">test</div>
  <div class="elementor-post">test</div>
  <div class="elementor-post">test</div>
  <div class="elementor-post">test</div>
  <div class="elementor-post">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Oscargeek - it looks like this just fades everything out but nothing 'slides in'.

Comment: with `animate({ height: 0 })`  should be the same effect that slideUp, sure that don't work?

Comment: Sorry, Oscargeek - when I click on Run code snippet, all of the test text just appears at once?

Comment: Yes, then you can click in each item to view the slideUp() and fadeOut() at the same time. I guess that the effect is on an event ¿no? It's only to check that work, you can execute where you like.

Comment: I 'm not explaining myself very well, apologies - If you go here: https://undsgn.com/uncode/blog/blog-boxed-grid?id=index-15588655905&ucat=7 and click on one of the filters, you will see the blog posts are fading and sliding in one by one... that's what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: In that blog don't use slideUp() effect :S The easy way is searching a jQuery plugin that do this effect. slideUp() in jQuery hide the element decreasing the height of element.

Comment: @ShaunTaylor check the code now, the times are so slow to can check, but with 1000/1500 i think that work. You need to set an overlay: hidden in the parent div to avoid the scroll.